# WCF Service Ececuting in Local host but when hosted in IIS than its not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

My WCF Service is working fine when I am debugging it manually, but when I host the same service in IIS, add the link of hosted service to my Web application then the service gets executed but it is not creating the file that I want. Here is my WCF service code.

```
public void Deploy(string clientName)
{
    string folderpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\" + "WCFFilesForIISHosting" + "\\";
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderpath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
    }
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderpath);
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.txt").Where(p => p.Extension == ".txt").ToArray();

    TextWriter tw;
    string text = clientName;

    string path = folderpath + "Clients" + ".txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path).Dispose();
        tw = new StreamWriter(path);
        tw.WriteLine(text.ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
        tw.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        File.AppendAllText(path, text.ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: most probably it's a permission error by hosting service. try setting permission of folder to 777 for testing. Don't forget to change it afterwards

Comment: Issue Solved :
 It was the "Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)" piece of code that was not able to locate the Directory...I made the directory pointing to C:\ and it worked.

Comment: You may want to post that comment as an answer and then mark it as such.